# I want to make an exception in this jQuery rule

Tags: jquery, toggle, slide, nav

I have coded so that if you click outside the pop-out nav, it closes the nav, however there is a button called #button that is outside the nav. When I click it it just 're-slides' the nav back out instead of getting rid of it.

the button has its own separate line of code that toggles slide.

I have a feeling that when I click on that button, the first rule ive mentioned gets triggered, then the button re activates slide out instead of in, as the previous rule I mentioned toggled off of it.

I want to be able to use the button when nav is out, but still retain use of rule allowing me to exit off when clicking outside the nav.

Please help

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#button").click(function(){
    jQuery("#popoutnav").slideToggle();
});
jQuery("#cross").click(function(){
    jQuery("#popoutnav").slideToggle();
});
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
var container = $("#popoutnav");

if (!container.is(e.target) 
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
{
    container.hide();
}
});
```

Comment: You can probably add an if statement to your #button click event, to see if `$('#popoutnav').is(':visible')` (I think that's the syntax...going from memory).

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the propagation of the same event on the button so that if it executes the body click logic will not happen.

```js
jQuery(function($){
 var $popupnav = $('#popupnav');
 $popupnav.hide();
 
 $('#button').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $popupnav.slideToggle();
 });
 
 $('body').on('click', function(e){
  if (!$popupnav.is(e.target) && !$popupnav.has(e.target).length) {
   $popupnav.slideUp();
  }
 });
});
```

```css
#popupnav {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">toggle</button>
<div id="popupnav"></div>
```